# join tables in one query with differet column name

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to make a dynamic Sitemap. But the problem is I have different Tables with url. How can bring It in one query ,I know answer is  already there but I am not understanding Please guide

TABLE A

```
    | id  | addpage                                |
-------------------------------------------------------------
    |  1  | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask|
    |     |                                        |
    |     |                                        |
    |     |                                        |
```

TABLE B

```
    | id  | pagename                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------
    |  1  | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask|
    |     |                                        |
    |     |                                        |
    |     |                                        |
```

TABLE C

```
    | id  | pagename                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------
    |  1  | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask|
    |     |                                        |
    |     |                                        |
    |     |                                        |
```

Comment: What the result should be? Also read about `UNION`

Answer (score 2):

use `SQL UNION Operator` ([learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp))

> The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more
> SELECT statements.
>
> - Every SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
> - The columns must also have similar data types
> - The columns in every SELECT statement must also be in the same order

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question but not related to this will you help please, no one answering. Can I ask ?